# QuickBlox sample video chat Unauthorized Error

Tags: ios, quickblox, videochat

I am trying to run the Quickblox Video Chat sample to see if this is something that can be integrated to my app, but the sample setup is incomplete in how to get it to work.
  https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-ios

I have created an app, put my app keys in the sample, and created 2 users and put their information there, but still does not work.

Please, when you put sample code write ALL the information you need to get it to work.  The read me file mentions nothing about having to setup new users and even I figured this out, it still does not authenticate, just giving the error "Unauthorized"

This is the code they have for the users:

```
    // This is test oppoents. This is 2 users' logins/passwords & ids

self.testOpponents = @[@"videoChatUser1", @65421,
                     @"videoChatUser2", @65422];
```

I created my own users in my registered Quickblox app and replaced the above code, but it still does not work.  Is the password information supposed to go someplace here????  What is causing this to fail???

Answer (score 0):

If you quickly go through whole sample, you can see some comments there

for example, look at this file
https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-ios/blob/master/VideoChat-sample-ios/AppDelegate.m

you can see comments that explain what all these values mean

```
//
// There are tests oppoents. There are 2 users' logins/passwords & ids
//
    self.testOpponents = @[@"videoChatUser1", @65421,
                      @"videoChatUser2", @65422];
```

**videoChatUser1** - login and password of the 1st user,

**65421** - ID of the 1st user

**videoChatUser2** - login and password of the 2nd user,

**65421** - ID of the 2nd user

hope this help

Comment: Sorry but I still do not understand the logic here. Are you saying VideoChatUser1 is the username AND the password?  I do not understand where to put the password and in what form?  Please give a complete example.  If I just put what you have here, I only get an error and it does not work.  Give a step by step example, starting with creating a user in your app.  Then what?  I tried just replacing the username with the one I created and the ID but when I log I. It just says Error ( Unauthorized )

Comment: Please check this file https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-ios/blob/master/VideoChat-sample-ios/ViewController/SplashViewController/SplashViewController.m

lines 49 and 50, i think it's clear